# SCCM 2012 application install "Failed" in client Software Center

Tags: logging, configurationmanager, sccm

We're using SCCM 2012 and I'm packaging all of our application and testing them as I go.  Some only have .exe's and are more difficult than the .msi's.  Some have no documentation and I'm trying different types of command line switches to see what works.

The only way I am able to test these out is create the application, deployment type, and deployment and then push it down to a test client I have.

When an application downloads and then immediately fails, which logs can I review for more information?  Looking at client logs for SCNotify, Execmgr, and Windows\CCM\Logs doesn't reveal much.  The server side logs don't appear to shed any additional light either.

I'm not doing a task sequence so SMSTS.Log isn't much help.

Where do you guys begin troubleshooting when you think you have the correct command line but the application downloads to client and then fails?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you figured this out already but:

[Technical Reference for Log Files in Configuration Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh427342.aspx)

That's a list of client-side logs and what they do. They are located in `Windows\CCM\Logs`

`AppEnforce.log` will show you the actual command-line executed and the resulting exit code for each Deployment Type (only for the new style ConfigMgr Applications)

This is my go-to for troubleshooting apps.  Haven't really found any other logs that are exceedingly useful.

Comment: Thanks for a good link, @ctd25. Would also like to mention `CMTrace.exe` for viewing the logs (haven't used it yet myself, though).

Answer (score 0):

The `execmgr.log` will show the commandline and ccmcache folder used for installation. Typically, required apps don't show on `appenforce.log` and some clients will have outdated `appenforce` or no `ppenforce.log` files.
`execmgr.log` also shows required hidden uninstall actions as well.

You may want to save the blog link. I still reference it from time to time.